# I have a file with all the iptable settings. How do I load this into my server?

Tags: iptables

My system admin gave me a file with iptables rules. What command do I type in to load this?

I watched him do it before, and he did it in 1 line!
Something like...iptables > thefile.dat ????

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> My system admin gave me a file with iptables rules. What command do I type in to load this?

```
iptables-restore < file-with-iptables-rules.txt
```

> I watched him do it before, and he did it in 1 line! Something like...iptables > thefile.dat ????

```
iptables-save > file-with-iptables-rules.txt
```

Comment: Is it possible to import from a URL?

eg:

``iptables-restore < http://git.company.com/Company/iptables-rules/blob/master/iptables-rules.txt``

Comment: I believe the iptables-restore command functions local to the filesystem; however, nothing stops you from piping a data stream into it via curl or wget.  So in theory, instead of just specifying a URL, you would fetch the contents of the file and pipe that to the command.

Comment: Thanks @avery-payne Can you demonstrate what that might look like?

Comment: @Jay Probably something similar to `curl -s SOME_URL | iptables-restore`.

Comment: If you want to do this with sudo you'll also need to use tee:
sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables/rules.txt
sudo iptables-restore /etc/iptables/rules.txt

Comment: @jorfus All `tee` does is write to both stdout and a file at the same time. You certainly don't need to use it.

Comment: My point is that the answer will only work if you run it as root (you probably want to save your firewall rules in /etc/ since you don't want just anyone mucking around with your rules).
So the following will fail: sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables-rules.txt (I leave it as an exercise for the reader to explore why).
You can either become root first (fine, but that's not great security hygiene) or do it in one command with sudo. If you want to do that you can use the form: echo something | sudo tee filename.txt
That pattern is a good thing to know.

Comment: If you do the update over ssh, you probably want `iptables-apply` instead. It safeguards you from accidental lock-out.

Answer (score 9):

You **load** an iptables configuration file using iptables-restore

```
iptables-restore thefile.dat
```

This has effect immediately. However for this settings to be **persistent over system reboot** they must be saved. On most distributions this can be done with.

```
/etc/init.d/iptables save
```

As mentioned in other answers the configuration can be **saved** using

```
iptables-save > thesavefile.dat
```

The file itself is a **text file** and can be edited with any texteditor and then reloaded into iptables using the iptables-restore command.

Answer (score 3):

To import an iptables script into your ruleset

```
iptables-restore < /path/to/firewall_script
```

Comment: Do I have to restart iptables once I type this command?

Comment: No, you shouldn need to restart

Comment: Is it possible to import from a URL?
eg:

iptables-restore < http://git.company.com/Company/iptables-rules/blob/master/iptables-rules.txt